# Multiple colors in div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want a div that looks like this [image]
How do i set the squares to 100x100px and reapeat the process?

Comment: Have you tried anything???

Comment: Have you tried any CSS pattern? Examples you can find [here](http://lea.verou.me/css3patterns/) or [here](https://css-tricks.com/stripes-css/) or you can use Pattern Generator like https://patternizer.com/ or http://www.patternify.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be pure css:

```css
#dotted {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 100px;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, #DF0000, #DF0000 100px, #000000 100px, #000000 200px)
}
```

```html
<div id="dotted">
</div>
```

Here's a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/knkp55yk/2/).

If you want to set the `width` and the `height` of the squares, just change the normal `height` and fix the `100px` inside of the `background` to whatever you like. The `200px` have to be the double of the `100px`.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a div with the width you need it to be for example 2000px, set background to that div with the image you want to repeat, the 2 squares black and red in your case, ande repeat it.

```
#div {
    width: 2000px;
    height: 100px;
    background: url("yourpicture.png") repeat-x;
}
```

Comment: repeat y , are you sure?

Comment: my mistake, repeat-x

Answer (score 1):

If this is just solid background color you can use `repeating-linear-gradient()`.

```
background: repeating-linear-gradient(to right, black, black 10px, red 10px, red 20px);
```

Or `linear-gradient` with specific `background-size`.

```
background-image: linear-gradient(to right, black 10px, red 10px, red 20px);
background-size: 20px 10px;
```

Both variants will do the job.

```css
.div1 {
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(to right, black, black 10px, red 10px, red 20px);
  height: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.div2 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, black 10px, red 10px, red 20px);
  background-size: 20px 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">

</div>
<div class="div2">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with pure css.
Have an image with a black and red squares and then repeat it on the X axis

[Something like this.](https://jsfiddle.net/Havock94/Lby8hn8d/)

```
div{
    background-image: url("......");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
```

}